# How to fix php form validation password error?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am using Mac OS, mamp, phpmyadmin to create a simple login form. I have created my database in php myadmin and the first user. I am certain the username and password are correct (as per my database) but I receive the error that the password is incorrect.

I was loosely following this tutorial https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

I believe this may be causing the error but i'm unsure.

```
$hashed_password = $row["password"];
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
```

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";

        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                    if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                        $id = $row["id"];
                        $username = $row["username"];
                        $hashed_password = $row["password"];
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    unset($pdo);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to be taken to my welcome screen.

Answer (score 0):

To fix I replaced

```
$hashed_password = $row["password"];
if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
```

with

```
$hashed_password = password_hash( $_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
if(password_verify($_POST["password"], $hashed_password)){
```

This hash passwords before storing them in db then verifies the plan text against the hashed password

Comment: No, is always working but is not correct. You are transform a password and match itself against the same. Your condition is always true even if the user is not authorized. I edited my answer, please check it

Answer (score -1):

Verify method is expecting the hashed password. Your `$row["password"]`contains hashed password (if you use `password_hash()` function in user registration) while the password received with `$_POST` is a plain text password.

Use the following:

```
    if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $row["password"])) {
      // User authorized
    } else {
      // User non authorized
    }
```

Comment: This fixed the issue but why?

Comment: How do you store the password inside the database? Plain text?

Comment: Likely your password inside database is in plain text. `password_verify` method verifies that a password matches a hash but you are passing to it (as a second argument) a plain text instead of a hash. However is not safe to store a plain text password inside database because who has the database access knows all the passwords. So, encrypt the passwords before they are stored.

Comment: Worth noting is that you should hash them, not encrypt.